# Windows 11 WSL automount drives and auto-start

Tags: powershell, mount, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I'm running some servers on my Ubuntu instance on WSL through windows 11.
For those servers to run, I need to mount a hard drive, which i do with the command

```
wsl --mount //./PHYSICALDRIVE0
```

The above command needs to be run from the PowerShell as Administrator
After that i need to launch my default instance

Is there a way to automate this process so it happens silently when i boot windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the windows task scheduler, create a new task, and tell it to:

- run at startup in the scheduling settings
- run as administrator (with highest privileges)
- run even if user is not logged in,

set it to launch a program: `powershell.exe` with arguments `-C wsl --mount //./PHYSICALDRIVE0`

Comment: i'm going to try it out soon and will accept your answer as correct when confirmed. Thanks

Comment: one more question: that task will only mount the drive, it won't start my machine after the mount. Is there a way to do these two operations sequentially on the same task? or am i missing something? thank you

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez running a wsl command should start up wsl? Otherwise, powershell will take multiple commands separated by semicolon, like `-C foo x;bar y` etc. Starting from task scheduler args means no multiline (and special characters can be weird), so usually just call a script if you need anything complicated.

Comment: It is difficult to have task scheduler run wsl commands at boot, although pretty straightforward to have it run those commands when a user first logs in. See the issues discussed in [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1754734/how-to-run-wsl-on-windows-11-boot-as-service/1765794#1765794). I will be very interested if you are successful!